# How do I make my annotation callout lead to a different view controller?

Tags: ios, objective-c, dictionary, annotations

I appreciate all answers. Thank you so much for your time.
I've looked for awhile but can't find a solution to my problem...

I let the restaurant user set a pin that includes the restaurant picture, a text title (they write this right before they set the pin), a text subtitle (they write this right before they set the pin), and a info button callout.

I want to make it so that when the user presses the info button callout, he/she is brought to a page that displays the restaurant picture, the restaurant name, the title, subtitle, and name. Also I need there to be a back button that brings the user right back to the map view in the first view controller.

So there will be numerous different restaurants and I need to somehow get the data from the first view controller's pin to the second view controller.

I currently have this code in my first view controller to display the annotations

```
-(MKAnnotationView *) mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView viewForAnnotation:    (id<MKAnnotation>)annotation {

if ([annotation isKindOfClass:[MKUserLocation class]])
    return nil;
MKPinAnnotationView *MyPin=[[MKPinAnnotationView alloc] initWithAnnotation:annotation reuseIdentifier:@"User"];


UIButton *rightButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeDetailDisclosure];
[rightButton addTarget:nil action:nil forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
MyPin.rightCalloutAccessoryView = rightButton;
MyPin.draggable = NO;
MyPin.highlighted = YES;
MyPin.animatesDrop=TRUE;
MyPin.canShowCallout = YES;
UIImageView *myCustomImage = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"CorgiRunner2 Final.png"]];
myCustomImage.image = profPic;
myCustomImage.frame = CGRectMake(0,0,31,31);
MyPin.leftCalloutAccessoryView = myCustomImage;

return MyPin;
}
```

What do I have to do to display a restaurant's specific info after the callout in the first view controller is pressed? Also, remember I somehow need access to the text in the first view controller.

Again, thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1):

1. Create a subclass of MKAnnotation that has a restaurant property.
2. When the button is tapped, it should call `-mapView:annotationView:calloutAccessoryControlTapped:`. You can then use `annotationView.annotation.restaurant` to know what restaurant you have. You can tell it to present the next view controller here and pass along that restaurant.

Comment: Can you give me more specifics into each step please?